# Adding an entry to nested zip File using commons.apache.compress

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

My Zip File structure is something like this:

`t1.zip` **-->** `t2.zip` **-->** `sample.txt`

I want to replace **sample.txt**. If it's one level, I was able to do it. Please help me with multi level nested zip files.

My Sample Code

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("t1.zip");
ZipArchiveEntry ze = zipFile.getEntry("t2.zip"); // So It works fine
```

I tried

```
ZipArchiveEntry ze = zipFile.getEntry("t2.zip/sample.txt"); // returns null
```

My intention was to follow Example from the apache's documentation page as this

```
ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(new File("sample.txt")); // Should I t2.zip/sample.txt ?
entry.setSize(size);
zipOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);
zipOutput.write(contentOfEntry);
zipOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
```

But I am not clear, how to put the archive entry 2 level inside ?

Comment: I added my sample piece of code that I tried

Answer (score -1):

You have to use

```
new ZipArchiveEntry(new File("sample.txt"), "sample.txt");
```

to set the file into the root folder and

```
new ZipArchiveEntry(new File("sample.txt"), "new folder/sample.txt");
```

to set into a new folder called "new folder".